# jquery сравнивать две кнопки и нажимать на вторую

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5, bootstrap

Нужна помощь в jquery
Имеется ряд кнопок, с одинаковыми атрибутами, необходимо по нажатию на кнопку(синею) с атрибутом "data-myval="333"" нажималась кнопка(красная) с атрибутом "data-myres="333""

То есть нажимая на кнопку .btn-tbumbs аналогичная кнопка .btn-param с таким-же атрибутом должна так-же нажиматься

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
            <div class="my-1"> <button class="btn btn-primary btn-tbumbs" data-myval="111">btn - 111</button> </div>
            <div class="my-1"> <button class="btn btn-primary btn-tbumbs" data-myval="222">btn - 222</button> </div>
            <div class="my-1"> <button class="btn btn-primary btn-tbumbs" data-myval="333">btn - 333</button> </div>
            <div class="my-1"> <button class="btn btn-primary btn-tbumbs" data-myval="444">btn - 444</button> </div>
            <div class="my-1"> <button class="btn btn-primary btn-tbumbs" data-myval="555">btn - 555</button> </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            <div class="my-1"> <button class="btn btn-danger btn-param" data-myres="111">btn2 - 111</button> </div>
            <div class="my-1"> <button class="btn btn-danger btn-param" data-myres="222">btn2 - 222</button> </div>
            <div class="my-1"> <button class="btn btn-danger btn-param" data-myres="333">btn2 - 333</button> </div>
            <div class="my-1"> <button class="btn btn-danger btn-param" data-myres="444">btn2 - 444</button> </div>
            <div class="my-1"> <button class="btn btn-danger btn-param" data-myres="555">btn2 - 555</button> </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Так - же ссылка на редактор: https://jsfiddle.net/synapse3/Lrc7vasw/7/

Спасибо большое

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну вот как вариант типа)) И без JQ

```js
const blueButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('btn btn-primary btn-tbumbs');

for(let i = 0; i < blueButtons.length; i++) {
    blueButtons[i].addEventListener('click', event => {
    const myval = event.target.getAttribute('data-myval');
    document.querySelector(`[data-myres="${myval}"]`).click();
  });
}

//for testing
const redButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('btn btn-danger btn-param');
for(let i = 0; i < redButtons.length; i++) {
    redButtons[i].addEventListener('click', event => {
    console.log('clicked on ', event.target);
  });
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
            <div class="my-1"> <button class="btn btn-primary btn-tbumbs" data-myval="111">btn - 111</button> </div>
            <div class="my-1"> <button class="btn btn-primary btn-tbumbs" data-myval="222">btn - 222</button> </div>
            <div class="my-1"> <button class="btn btn-primary btn-tbumbs" data-myval="333">btn - 333</button> </div>
            <div class="my-1"> <button class="btn btn-primary btn-tbumbs" data-myval="444">btn - 444</button> </div>
            <div class="my-1"> <button class="btn btn-primary btn-tbumbs" data-myval="555">btn - 555</button> </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            <div class="my-1"> <button class="btn btn-danger btn-param" data-myres="111">btn2 - 111</button> </div>
            <div class="my-1"> <button class="btn btn-danger btn-param" data-myres="222">btn2 - 222</button> </div>
            <div class="my-1"> <button class="btn btn-danger btn-param" data-myres="333">btn2 - 333</button> </div>
            <div class="my-1"> <button class="btn btn-danger btn-param" data-myres="444">btn2 - 444</button> </div>
            <div class="my-1"> <button class="btn btn-danger btn-param" data-myres="555">btn2 - 555</button> </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

С новыми версиями Bootstrap, JQuery не нужен кстати.

```js
let buttonsBlue = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('[data-myval]'));

buttonsBlue.forEach((button) => {
  button.addEventListener('click', (ev) => {
    let redButton = document.querySelector(`[data-myres='${ev.target.dataset.myval}']`)
    redButton.click()

    //for demo
    redButton.style.opacity = .7;
    
  })
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
      <div class="my-1"> <button class="btn btn-primary btn-tbumbs" data-myval="111">btn - 111</button> </div>
      <div class="my-1"> <button class="btn btn-primary btn-tbumbs" data-myval="222">btn - 222</button> </div>
      <div class="my-1"> <button class="btn btn-primary btn-tbumbs" data-myval="333">btn - 333</button> </div>
      <div class="my-1"> <button class="btn btn-primary btn-tbumbs" data-myval="444">btn - 444</button> </div>
      <div class="my-1"> <button class="btn btn-primary btn-tbumbs" data-myval="555">btn - 555</button> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
      <div class="my-1"> <button class="btn btn-danger btn-param" data-myres="111">btn2 - 111</button> </div>
      <div class="my-1"> <button class="btn btn-danger btn-param" data-myres="222">btn2 - 222</button> </div>
      <div class="my-1"> <button class="btn btn-danger btn-param" data-myres="333">btn2 - 333</button> </div>
      <div class="my-1"> <button class="btn btn-danger btn-param" data-myres="444">btn2 - 444</button> </div>
      <div class="my-1"> <button class="btn btn-danger btn-param" data-myres="555">btn2 - 555</button> </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -2):

bootstrap4:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/buttons/#toggle-states

jquery:
https://api.jquery.com/click/

https://api.jquery.com/attr/

как вариант

Comment: Пожалуйста, примите во внимание, в разделе справки: [Почему и как удаляются некоторые ответы?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers), кроме всего прочего, 
сказано: _являются всего лишь ссылкой на другой сайт_. Это сообщение, пожалуйста, или поправте, или удалите.